# HTMLFile COM object (IHTMLDocument2) breaks in Edge mode, sometimes

Tags: html, powershell, com

I have a web page as a simple string.  I'm trying to make an HTMLDocument out of it using the `HTMLFile` COM object:

```bsh
$page = @'
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <title>A Title</title>
    <script src="/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="findme">Hello</div>
    <div>Nope</div>
</body>
</html>
'@

$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($page);

$html = New-Object -Com "HTMLFile";
try {
    # Powershell 4
    $html.IHTMLDocument2_write($bytes);
} catch {
    # Powershell 5
    $html.write($bytes);
}

write $html.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

As written, this outputs

```html
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>A Title</title>
    <script src="/index.js"></script></head>
```

Note that the entire `<body>` tag is gone.  If I change the `meta` tag from `IE=edge` (or `IE=11`) to `IE=9`, the output is correct and includes the `<body>` tag and all its contents.  The crazy part is that it works with `IE=edge` if I take out the `<script>` tag, or if it's an inline script rather than a `src=` reference.

Did I do something wrong?  The HTML passes the W3C validator so I don't think it's faulty markup.  Is there a different mode I can set on the document before the call to `.write()` to have it parse successfully even with the `IE=edge` meta-tag?

PS: I wish this wasn't relevant, but it might matter that I don't have Office installed on this machine, because I think that would provide a different implementation for the COM object.  Win10 18363, Powershell 5.1.

Comment: does the edge engine HAVE a COM interface? also, the HTML parser seems to require IE ... and that IE be run at least once by the account that makes the call. something seems to require some sort of initialization before the COM interface can be reliably used.

Comment: I don't fully understand what it's actually doing under the hood, this is just the only suggested way I can find of turning a file or string-literal HTML page into a document that I can query (and we all know the perils of trying to comb through it with a regex...).  `IE=edge` does work sometimes, like if I take that `<script>` tag out.

Comment: ah! then edge does have a COM interface. i cannot test that - stuck on win7 since win10 runs S-L-O-W-L-Y on my old system. i will go back to lurking ... good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: I would consider looking at the NuGet package for [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp). You can use `$parser = [AngleSharp.Html.Parser.HtmlParser]::new()` and `$html = $parser.ParseDocument($page)` to parse a HTML string, such as the one above. I have found this to be the most reliable method and it also works well with PowerShell Core. Avoid Com objects and reliance on IE where possible.

Comment: I'm trying to write a script to run on older machines in a locked-down corporate environment, so I'm shooting for maximum compatibility and ideally zero external dependencies.  I've seen a bunch of people suggest libraries like that but I'd really like to make it work using only built-ins.